# AttributeError at /profiles/user-profile/2/ 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here I am using an api of notifications. here is the reference of that api [link](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications). I have follow the instructions given on the github read me file. But when i try to send an email by actor to recipient .it shows me the error **'int' object has no attribute '_meta'**. The actor field and recipient both accept user_ids and I have put them manually. But still didn't work.

profiles/Views.py

```
class UserProfileFollowToggle(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            user_to_toggle_pk=kwargs.get('pk')
            username_to_toggle = request.POST.get("username")
            profile_, is_following = UserProfile.objects.toggle_follow(request.user, request.user.id, user_to_toggle_pk ,username_to_toggle)
            return redirect(f'/profiles/{username_to_toggle}')
```

profiles/models.py

```
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def toggle_follow(self, request_user,user_id,user_to_toggle_pk, username_to_toggle):
        profile_ = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=request_user.username)
        is_following = False
        follower = profile_.follower.filter(username__iexact=username_to_toggle).first()
        if follower:
            profile_.follower.remove(follower.id)
            notify.send(user_id, recipient=user_to_toggle_pk, verb='unfollow you')
        else:
            new_follower = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username_to_toggle)
            profile_.follower.add(new_follower.id)
            notify.send(user_id, recipient=user_to_toggle_pk, verb='follow you')
            is_following = True
        return profile_, is_following
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\profiles\views.py", line 30, in post
    profile_, is_following = UserProfile.objects.toggle_follow(request.user, request.user.id, user_to_toggle_pk ,username_to_toggle)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\profiles\models.py", line 22, in toggle_follow
    notify.send(user_id, recipient=user_to_toggle_pk, verb='unfollow you')
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\notifications\base\models.py", line 288, in notify_handler
    actor_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(actor),
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 40, in get_for_model
    opts = self._get_opts(model, for_concrete_model)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 27, in _get_opts
    model = model._meta.concrete_model

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profiles/user-profile/2/
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

If more information is required than tell me in a comment section. I will update my question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the AttributeError is caused, because you are trying to pass a user pk to the send function

```
notify.send(user_id, recipient=user_to_toggle_pk, verb='unfollow you')
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but the send function expect an User object.
So try something like this..

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_to_toggle_pk)
notify.send(user_id, recipient=user, verb='unfollow you')
```

Comment: It worked but i have also updated the actor which is user_id in my code. you can update your answers and add that two by the way thank you. :)